# Calculate values of textboxes automatically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to calculate the value of the 1st 2 text boxes without a command button
Example i have 3 text boxes.

The first 2, where  the numbers will be inputed and the last 1 will be the sum or product and so on.
Now i want it to auto compute.
For example i have inputed values 2 and 3 on the 1st 2 text boxes then automatically the sum or product or whatever result will be displayed on the 3rd text box.
How am i able to do this? Thanks

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('#texttwo').keyup(function(){
    var textone;
    var texttwo;
    textone = parseFloat($('#textone').val());
    texttwo = parseFloat($('#texttwo').val());
    var result = textone + texttwo;
    $('#result').val(result.toFixed(2));
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <input type="text" name="value1" id="textone">
    <input type="text" name="value2" id="texttwo">
    <input type="text" name="result" id="result">
    </body>
    </head>
```

Comment: What you need is Javascript and possibly AJAX.

Comment: Maybe you should read a javascript tutorial, this is really basics.

Comment: can you give me some examples? or can you share a link pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using jQuery.
Include jQuery in your project by putting this in your `<head>`

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then, at the end of the file:

```
<script>
$('#texttwo').keyup(function(){
    var textone;
    var texttwo;
textone = parseFloat($('#textone').val());
texttwo = parseFloat($('#texttwo').val());
var result = textone + texttwo;
$('#result').val(result.toFixed(2));


    });
</script>
```

This will give you the result when ever you change the value of the second box.

You will need to do this, too:

Change

```
    <input type=text name=value1>
    <input type=text name=value2>
    <input type=text name=result>
```

to:

```
    <input type="text" name="value1" id="textone">
    <input type="text" name="value2" id="texttwo">
    <input type="text" name="result" id="result">
```

**EDIT**

This is my entire file:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" name="value1" id="textone">
<input type="text" name="value2" id="texttwo">
<input type="text" name="result" id="result">

<script>
    $('#texttwo').keyup(function(){
        var textone;
        var texttwo;
        textone = parseFloat($('#textone').val());
        texttwo = parseFloat($('#texttwo').val());
        var result = textone + texttwo;
        $('#result').val(result.toFixed(2));


    });
</script>
```

Comment: You'r welcome, please mark the answer as right if you feel it solved your problem.

Comment: Made a little change, have forgotten );

Comment: nothings happening sir its not displaying on the 3rd text box sorry im noob in programming

Comment: Did you copy the latest edit, from 7 minutes ago? In the first version there was the ); missing at the end of the script. I just copied it, it's working.

Comment: yes sir but it did not displayed as well i will post what i did maybe theres wrong with what im doing i really am not familiar with this

Comment: thank you very much sir i really am noob in programing

Comment: Well, should by working. Your last closing tag is wrong, change the last </head> to </html>

Comment: Welcome! Remember that this will only change the value if you alter the second textfield. If you want it to calculate on change of first textbox, change this: $('#texttwo').keyup(function(){    to:  $('#texttwo #textone').keyup(function(){

Comment: sir @michael i want to add another textbox that will tell if the result of the 3rd textbox is fail or pass example if the value of textbox3 is 4 then it is failed but if it is 3 or lower then it is passed thanks for the help sir

Comment: Not sure if I get you right, but try this:   

if (result > 3.00){
            $('#fail').val('FAIL');
        }
            else {
            $('#fail').val('TRUE');
        }
add this directly after $('#result').val(result.toFixed(2)); you will also need to create a fourth input with id "fail"